# Mudar valor JTextField de outra classe ou de forma automática

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Achei algumas questões similares na versão em inglês, mas não consegui resolver.

Tenho uma classe Caldeira, com os seguintes atributos:

- Temperatura da caldeira;
- quantLitrosAgua;
- Temperatura do fogo;

Nesse programa vou ter que manter a caldeira sempre acima de uma temperatura mínima para não parar de funcionar ou abaixo de uma temperatura máxima para não explodir. Para isso a medida que a água evaporar acrescento mais água (para não esquentar demais), e se acrescentar água demais e a temperatura baixar muito, aumento a temperatura do fogo.

O problema é que preciso fazer em 3 classes diferentes (Caldeira, AumentarFogo e AcrescentarAgua - cada uma em uma tela diferente), usando o padrão de projeto Singleton.

Então tenho um botão (aumentar temperatura) para abrir uma tela onde posso aumentar a temperatura do fogo e assim aumentar a temperatura da caldeira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois vou ter o botão(e classe/tela) de acrescentar água também, mas só fiz o de fogo por enquanto.

Não consigo atualizar os campos `JTextField` das temperaturas (temperatura do fogo(`jTextFieldMostraTempFogo`) -  e da caldeira (`jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira`) de uma maneira que fique legal.  Ao clicar no botão Aumentar Fogo dentro classe (tela) `AumentarFogo`. Os campos são esses:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1ª - Tentativa:

```
public void preencherTemperaturas() { 

jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaCaldeira));
jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaFogo));

}
```

Criei esse método na classe Caldeira e o chamei dentro do botão Aumentar Fogo na classe AumentarFogo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void jButtonAumentarFogoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    

    Caldeira.getInstance().aumentarFogo(10); //acrescenta +10 na temp. do fogo
    Caldeira.getInstance().preencherTemperaturas();

}
```

O engraçado é que de fato altera os atributos, mas não atualiza o jText.

2ª Tentativa (essa funciona, mas só atualiza quando abro novamente a tela AumentarFogo:

```
private void jButtonAbrirTelaFogoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    AumentarFogo aumentarFogo = new AumentarFogo();
    aumentarFogo.setVisible(true);

    //única jeito que funciona.
    jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaCaldeira));
    jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaFogo));
}
```

Ou seja, só consigo alterar os valores da `JTextField` quando executo um comando dentro da própria classe caldeira. Mas os valores dos atributos estão sendo alterados quando clico no botão da classe AumentarFogo. Já tentei várias coisas, tentei colocar no botão voltar, já que ele que manda retornar para a classe principal, mas também não dá certo.

Pensei em usar um listener com timer conforme vi em algumas pergunta do stack em inglês, mas não consegui implementar de jeito nenhum, então resolvi ver se teria alguma outra maneira.

As variáveis jText não estão estáticas. Até coloquei elas assim para fazer um teste, mas aí que elas não alteram de forma alguma, nem mandando atualizar de dentro da classe Caldeira.

Classes completas:

**Classe Caldeira:**

```
package caldeira;

public class Caldeira extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    private static Caldeira caldeira = null; //declaração da classe static conforme padrão de projeto Singleton

    private final int TEMPERATURAMAXIMA = 500; //temperatura máxima em Cº que a caldeira pode ficar
    private final int TEMPERATURAMINIMA = 100; //temperatura mínima em Cº que a caldeira pode ficar
    private final int TEMPERATURAMAXIMAFOGO = 600; //temperatura máxima em Cº que pode colocar o fogo

    private static int temperaturaCaldeira = 120; // valores iniciais dos atributos
    private static int quantLitrosAgua = 100;
    private static int temperaturaFogo = 130;

    private Caldeira() { //construtor privado conforme padrão de projeto Singleton
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaCaldeira)); //ja instancia o campo de texto tempcaldeira com o valor
        jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaFogo)); //ja instancia o campo de texto tempfogo com o valor
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void despejarLitrosDeAgua(int despejarLitrosDeAgua) { //acrescentar água para diminuir temperatura da caldeira
        quantLitrosAgua += 10;
    }

    public void aumentarFogo(int aumentoDoFogo) { // aumentar a temperatura do fogo para aumentar a temp. da caldeira
        temperaturaCaldeira += aumentoDoFogo;
        temperaturaFogo += aumentoDoFogo;
    }

    public static synchronized Caldeira getInstance() {
        if (caldeira == null) {
            caldeira = new Caldeira();
        }

        return caldeira;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButtonAbrirTelaFogo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButtonAbrirTelaAgua = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextFieldMostraTempFogo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("C A L D E I R A O  ");
        setResizable(false);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jButtonAbrirTelaFogo.setText("Aumentar Temperatura");
        jButtonAbrirTelaFogo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonAbrirTelaFogoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButtonAbrirTelaAgua.setText("Diminuir Temperatura");

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 266, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 120, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setEditable(false);
        jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Temperatura Caldeirão");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Temperatura Fogo");

        jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setEditable(false);
        jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextFieldMostraTempFogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldMostraTempFogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButtonAbrirTelaFogo)
                            .addComponent(jButtonAbrirTelaAgua))))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(63, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                        .addComponent(jButtonAbrirTelaFogo)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButtonAbrirTelaAgua)))
                .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("nome");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(171, 171, 171)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public void preencherTemperaturas() { // uma das tentativas de alterar o valor dos campos de temperatura: NÃO FUNCIONA
        jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaCaldeira));
        jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaFogo));
    }

    private void jButtonAbrirTelaFogoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
        AumentarFogo aumentarFogo = new AumentarFogo();
        aumentarFogo.setVisible(true);

        //única jeito que funciona. Mas fica ruim ter que clicar em aumentar fogo de novo para atualizar.
        jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaCaldeira));
        jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaFogo));
    }                                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Caldeira.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Caldeira.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Caldeira.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Caldeira.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Caldeira().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonAbrirTelaAgua;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonAbrirTelaFogo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldMostraTempFogo;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Classe AumentarFogo:**

```
package caldeira;


public class AumentarFogo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public AumentarFogo() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButtonAumentarFogo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButtonVoltar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("AumentarFogo");
        setResizable(false);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jButtonAumentarFogo.setText("Aumentar Fogo");
        jButtonAumentarFogo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonAumentarFogoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Aumenta a temperatura do Fogo");
        jLabel1.setToolTipText("");

        jButtonVoltar.setText("Voltar");
        jButtonVoltar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonVoltarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButtonAumentarFogo))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                        .addComponent(jButtonVoltar)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButtonAumentarFogo)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButtonVoltar)
                .addGap(9, 9, 9))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(45, 45, 45))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButtonVoltarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        Caldeira caldeira = Caldeira.getInstance();
        Caldeira.getInstance().preencherTemperaturas(); // NÃO FUNCIONA
        dispose();

    }                                             

    private void jButtonAumentarFogoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    

        Caldeira.getInstance().aumentarFogo(10);
        Caldeira.getInstance().preencherTemperaturas(); //NÃO FUNCIONA

    }                                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AumentarFogo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AumentarFogo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AumentarFogo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AumentarFogo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AumentarFogo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonAumentarFogo;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonVoltar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Onde está o padrao singleton nas classes? Não nada a respeito. É realmente necessário usar singleton para isso? a api já possui recursos, chamados listeners, para isso.

Comment: ué, o padrão singleton está no construtor privado, no método "public static synchronized Caldeira getInstance()" e no uso de getInstance na outra classe. Realmente acho que não é ideal usar o padrão singleton neste caso, mas é trabalho de faculdade justamente para aprender o padrão singleton.

Comment: Luis, nada disso é necessário, veja minha resposta abaixo, você complicou algo simples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com algumas poucas alterações, foi possivel fazer seu código funcionar como esperado sem utilizar singleton. A principal delas é evitar trabalhar com múltiplos JFrames, pois para isso existe a classe [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html), que possibilita trabalhar com janelas dependentes de um JFrame ou de outras JDialogs. Alterando a classe `AumentarFogo` para `JDialog`, você não precisa utilizar singleton nem nada do tipo para trocar dados entre o frame principal e esta subjanela.

> Obs.: Como seu código é muito grande, vou comentar apenas as alterações principais que fiz, de restante, você pode conferir mais abaixo as duas classes atualizadas.

- Primeiramente alterei a herança da classe `AumentarFogo` para JDialog e fiz algumas alterações no construtor, para que ela possa iniciar corretamente. Você pode consultar a [documentação da classe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) citada para entender melhor seus parâmetros.
- no método do botão que aumenta o fogo, eu inseri a idéia de um "contador de cliques", desta forma, basta incrementar o contador cada vez que o botão for clicado e você conseguirá saber quanto deve aumentar no campo da outra tela.
- No método do botão voltar, com as mudanças feitas na classe `AumentarFogo`, se torna desnecessário existir, mas para não alterar demais, apenas deixei o `dispose()`nele.
- Como a tela modal mantém o acesso a tela principal interrompido até que seja fechada, para recuperarmos o valor do contador, criei o método `getContador()` que retornará o número de vezes que o botão foi clicado vezes o fator que você já utilizava para aumentar o valor do fogo.
- Agora na classe `Caldeira`, no método `AbrirTelaFogo`, deleguei o que você estava fazendo na outra classe, pois como transformei ela em JDialog, os métodos após o `aumentarFogo.setVisible(true);` só serão executados quando a outra tela for fechada.
- Dica: não utilize nomes idênticos para métodos e classes, ainda mais num código gigante desses, você torna o código mais ilegível ainda. Procure dar nomes diferentes, mas que façam sentido para o que a classe/método fazem de verdade.

Por fim, segue ambas as classes modificadas:

> classe `Caldeira`

```
import java.awt.Frame;

public class Caldeira extends javax.swing.JFrame {


private static Caldeira caldeira = null; //declaração da classe static conforme padrão de projeto Singleton

private final int TEMPERATURAMAXIMA = 500; //temperatura máxima em Cº que a caldeira pode ficar
private final int TEMPERATURAMINIMA = 100; //temperatura mínima em Cº que a caldeira pode ficar
private final int TEMPERATURAMAXIMAFOGO = 600; //temperatura máxima em Cº que pode colocar o fogo

private static int temperaturaCaldeira = 120; // valores iniciais dos atributos
private static int quantLitrosAgua = 100;
private static int temperaturaFogo = 130;

private Caldeira() { //construtor privado conforme padrão de projeto Singleton
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaCaldeira)); //ja instancia o campo de texto tempcaldeira com o valor
    jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaFogo)); //ja instancia o campo de texto tempfogo com o valor
    System.out.println("");
}

public void despejarLitrosDeAgua(int despejarLitrosDeAgua) { //acrescentar água para diminuir temperatura da caldeira
    quantLitrosAgua += 10;
}

public void aumentarFogo(int aumentoDoFogo) { // aumentar a temperatura do fogo para aumentar a temp. da caldeira
    temperaturaCaldeira += aumentoDoFogo;
    temperaturaFogo += aumentoDoFogo;
}

public static synchronized Caldeira getInstance() {
    if (caldeira == null) {
        caldeira = new Caldeira();
    }

    return caldeira;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButtonAbrirTelaFogo = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButtonAbrirTelaAgua = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextFieldMostraTempFogo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("C A L D E I R A O  ");
    setResizable(false);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    jButtonAbrirTelaFogo.setText("Aumentar Temperatura");
    jButtonAbrirTelaFogo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonAbrirTelaFogoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButtonAbrirTelaAgua.setText("Diminuir Temperatura");

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 266, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 120, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setEditable(false);
    jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Temperatura Caldeirão");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("Temperatura Fogo");

    jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setEditable(false);
    jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jTextFieldMostraTempFogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)))
            .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(40, 40, 40)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(35, 35, 35)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextFieldMostraTempFogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jButtonAbrirTelaFogo)
                        .addComponent(jButtonAbrirTelaAgua))))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(63, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(43, 43, 43)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                    .addComponent(jButtonAbrirTelaFogo)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButtonAbrirTelaAgua)))
            .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("nome");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(171, 171, 171)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public void preencherTemperaturas() { // uma das tentativas de alterar o valor dos campos de temperatura: NÃO FUNCIONA
    jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaCaldeira));
    jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaFogo));
}

private void jButtonAbrirTelaFogoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    AumentarFogo aumentarFogo = new AumentarFogo(this);
    aumentarFogo.setVisible(true);
    aumentarFogo(aumentarFogo.getcontador());
    preencherTemperaturas();

    //única jeito que funciona. Mas fica ruim ter que clicar em aumentar fogo de novo para atualizar.
    jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaCaldeira));
    jTextFieldMostraTempFogo.setText(Integer.toString(temperaturaFogo));
}                                                    

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Caldeira.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Caldeira.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Caldeira.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Caldeira.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Caldeira().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonAbrirTelaAgua;
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonAbrirTelaFogo;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldMostraTempCaldeira;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldMostraTempFogo;
// End of variables declaration      
}
```

> classe `AumentarFogo`

```
public class AumentarFogo extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private int contador;

public AumentarFogo(Frame owner) {
    //passa ao construtor do JDialog o vinculo entre a classe 
    // Caldeira e esta classe
    super(owner, true);
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
    contador = 0;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButtonAumentarFogo = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButtonVoltar = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("AumentarFogo");
    setResizable(false);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    jButtonAumentarFogo.setText("Aumentar Fogo");
    jButtonAumentarFogo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonAumentarFogoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Aumenta a temperatura do Fogo");
    jLabel1.setToolTipText("");

    jButtonVoltar.setText("Voltar");
    jButtonVoltar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonVoltarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButtonAumentarFogo))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                    .addComponent(jButtonVoltar)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButtonAumentarFogo)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButtonVoltar)
            .addGap(9, 9, 9))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(45, 45, 45))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButtonVoltarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // com as alterações feitas, este método não precisa fazer mais nada
    // a nao ser fechar a janela
    dispose();
}                                             

private void jButtonAumentarFogoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    // aqui você só incrementa o contador para no final
    // calcular quantas vezes irá aumentaro fogo
    contador++;
}  



public int getcontador() {
    //método para você consultar
    // quantas vezes foi clicado
    return contador * 10;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AumentarFogo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AumentarFogo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AumentarFogo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AumentarFogo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>


}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonAumentarFogo;
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonVoltar;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration     

}
```

Veja em funcionamento:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>